# My Lubuntu install has no manual entry for X; what do I need to install?

Tags: x11, man, lubuntu

I was wondering what I need to install in Lubuntu 18.04 for this problem?

```
$ man X
No manual entry for X
See 'man 7 undocumented' for help when manual pages are not available.

$ man x
No manual entry for x
```

Comment: State your OS. The packages differ between them.

Comment: This should give a hint: `man -k x | grep -i server`

Comment: In Lubuntu it should also be in `xorg-docs-core/`, as in my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you should try this:

```
man x
```

Is this what you're looking for?

```
NAME
       X - a portable, network-transparent window system
```

In Debian Jessie that's provided by the `xorg-docs-core` package.

In fact `man X` also works...

Answer (score 1):

On Linux `X` is usually a link to other program that servers as an X-server.
To check this run `type` followed by `ls -l`:

```
$ type X
X is /usr/bin/X

$ ls -l /usr/bin/X
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4 2018-Nov-16 10:09:55 /usr/bin/X -> Xorg
```

Now we see that `X` actually runs `Xorg` on my system, so `man xorg` will give all the details:

> ```
> NAME
>
>    Xorg - X11R7 X server
>
> DESCRIPTION
>
>    Xorg  is  a full featured X server that was originally designed for UNIX and UNIX-like operating systems
> ```

---

And if you want a generic manual you can run `man xserver`:

> ```
> NAME
>        Xserver - X Window System display server
>
> SYNOPSIS
>        X [option ...]
>
> DESCRIPTION
>        X  is the generic name for the X Window System display server. 
>        It is frequently a link or a copy of the appropriate server binary for driving the most frequently used server on a given machine.
> ```